# Onchange behavior of browser input type="date" on iOS for iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, date, ipad, safari

I have a 700-line HTML/JavaScript page that, among other things, validates dates.  It works on desktop OSs, Android, and iPhone but fails on iOS Safari 14.4 on iPad because the change event on `input type="date"` fires before the user makes a selection.

**Edit:** This happens, with slight variations, with Chrome and Firefox on iOS 14.4 on iPad.  Conjecture: all three are using the OS date picker and the underlying problem is iOS 14.4 for iPad.

A mostly-minimal example is this:

```js
document.getElementById("date1").addEventListener("change",dtChange);
document.getElementById("ckValue").addEventListener("click",getValue);
function dtChange(evt) {
    var val=document.getElementById("date1").value;
    alert('Change event signaled; value='+val);
}
function getValue() {
    var val=document.getElementById("date1").value;
    alert("Value of date ="+val);
}
```

```html
<form name="test" >
<input type="date" name="date1" id="date1"><br>
<br>
</form>
<button id="ckValue">Check Value</button>
```

It's in a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1jnqf5aL/1/

In this example run on iPad, when the form is initially loaded and the date item is touched/tapped, the change event fires immediately and the value of the input item is the current date.  My application detects the change event and emits a "Departure date must be in the future" error message before the user has had an opportunity to select a date.

With other operating systems, the change event does not fire until the user has selected a date in the calendar form.

I can make browsers in iPad behave, sort-of, by providing an initial `value=` attribute on the input element where the value is the current date in ISO 8601 format.  The trouble with that is, the current date is not a valid date in this application, so I don't want to show it to the user of the application.  Browser sniffing will fail if/when iOS for iPad is changed to behave similarly to other operating systems.

My question:  How can I accommodate, or "program around" this behavior of iOS on iPad without browser sniffing?  Or, have I missed something obvious and fundamental?

Comment: The version at jsfiddle works OK on iOS 14.4.

Comment: @RobG  Thanks for trying it.  With iOS 14.4 on iPad, when the page is first loaded, the date field is (correctly) blank, but as soon as I touch it, the change event fires and the alert is displayed with the current date.  After that, it *does* work.  My problem is that initial change event before the user has had a chance to select anything.  Same with the code snippet which you kindly converted for me.

Comment: I tried it on iPhone, but can see that on iPad it behaves as described. It seems that since the input doesn't have a value, Safari sets it to the current date, which dispatches a change event (I'd class that as a bug).

Comment: @RobG  Thanks for re-checking.  It's good to know that it works on iPhone.  I have a "don't use Safari" message on our page; I can change it to "don't use Safari on iPad."

Comment: @RobG Is there a way an ordinary mortal can report such a bug to Apple in a way that might get attention?  (Sorry for not knowing; I've always been a big iron kinda guy, starting with OS/360, which will date me, VM/370, then various Unices, with Windows as the desktop because that was company-issue.)

Comment: Ha, not likely! I've had bugs logged for Safari for years but who knows, you might get lucky: [*Feedback Assistant for Developers*](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Answer (score 1):

You can just set a condition when page load in iphone and when page laod in other os.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))
{
      $(".no_phone").on("blur", function() {
         alert("changed");
      })
}
else{
      $(".no_phone").on("change", function() {
         alert("changed");
      })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the blur event instead of the change event.